# Add range values to include exiting table partition in Azure synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

I need to add a new boundary value to the existing table .

```
CREATE TABLE [STG].[IHS_POLK]
(
    [CCYYQ_NBR] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [COUNTRY] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [STATE] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [COUNTY] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [ZIP] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [TOTAL] [varchar](10) NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    PARTITION
        ([CCYYQ_NBR] RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (20191, 20192, 20193, 20194, 20201, 20202, 20203, 20204, 20211, 20212, 20213, 20214, 20221, 20222, 20223, 20224, 20231, 20232, 20233, 20234, 20241, 20242, 20243, 20244, 20251, 20252, 20253, 20254))
)
GO
```

Now I need to add a value "20261" in the range . Please let me know the query to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alter statement as below, if data exists in table, disable column store index before and rebuild it after running this. Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-partition) for more details.

```
ALTER TABLE [STG].[IHS_POLK] SPLIT RANGE (20261);
```

[image]